# How to connect raspberry pi into Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, xbmc, raspberrypi

I just picked myself up a **raspberry pi**, I am trying to connect the pi to my computer via Ethernet to access my video files. So far it seems to not notice any ethernet connection to my computer.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on my pc and using **xbian** to run xbmc on my pi, but I would be open to raspbmc, openELEC or any others just looking for a solution.

Comment: Are you running XBMC on the Pi? What OS is running on the computer hosting the media files. Edit your question with that info and perhaps we can provide some help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect both the PC and the Pi to a router and then browse the network for each other.  DHCP should give the Pi a pretty predictable IP address.  You might have to SSH in.

But you cannot just connect the Ethernet from the Pi to the back of your computer

Unless of course you have a dual-NIC setup with an internal network setup on one and WAN on the other.